# PDO throwing errors to my class?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

I can enable PDO to throw error as exceptions to PDOException class.
Can I make it to throw it to my exception class?
Right now I have to code like this:

```
try {
    $sql = "query";
    $zap = $pdo->query($sql);
    $sql_d=array();
    if ($zap->execute($sql_d)) {

    }
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new dbException($zap->errorInfo(), $sql);
}
```

I want to PDO throw error to dbException class - not PDOException.

Comment: How would you expect it to know how to throw an exception type that is has no idea what it is in its code?  You will have to use an Exception wrapper as you are doing.

Comment: Some kind of param in PDO declaration?

Comment: I really don't think there's a way to do this.